# How can I create QColor objects in Qt for the SRGB color space?

Tags: qt, color-space

I can't seem to find (official or unofficial) documentation on Qt colors vs color spaces.

I would like to define QColor's for my Qt application. I am coming from an OS X background, where I am accustomed to having `[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:green:blue:alpha:]` and also  `[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:green:blue:alpha:]`, and other options as well.

Most of the time, I would like to use SRGB. How can I achieve that? It would be also good to know where using the default `QColor(int,int,int,int)` constructor leads to, but I suspect it will be device colors.

My target platform is mostly Windows, so if you can only come up with a platform-dependent way of creating QColor objects with components defined in the SRGB color space, go ahead!

Comment: The question would be how do you use the QColor object after the fact. QColor doesn't have a sRGB space...

Comment: One specific example is to use QPainter to draw a line with a specific sRGB color.

Comment: @ZsoltSzatmari In most cases, the `QPainter` will be drawing on a `QImage` (that's what a raster paint engine does for widgets!), so it's still device space. You'd need to somehow tell the user of the image (the platform window, for example) that the raster image has a specific color space. Qt doesn't let you do it directly, but you can inspect the platform plugin code and change things there.

Comment: "you can inspect the platform plugin code and change things there. " <= doing it the other way seems simpler, converting my sRGB values to device values and consistently using them.
One related problem is that I should be able to tell QImage (and libpng, indirectly) about the device color space.
It seems a bit strange to me that Qt's developers did not think of these matters.

Answer (score 1):

`QColor` is just a container for four ints. Everything depends on what you use it for. You'd need to show example code of how you use the `QColor` instance.

In most cases, though, `QColor` will end up being used by the raster paint engine back end. In such case, it has the meaning of the device color. Specifically, if you paint using `QColor`, it is not ever seen directly by OS X drawing functions. OS X is only passed a texture/image that has been already rendered by the raster paint engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 'In most cases' ? Is this somewhere documented, which cases will it be device color, when somewhere else?
If it's used as device color (as I suspected), then I need a way then to convert from srgb to device colors. Basically that's my question about.

Comment: @ZsoltSzatmari What I mean by "most cases" is that typically `QColor` ends up used by the raster paint engine. If you use it for some other purpose, you'll know it (say for printing, or for some non-raster I/O).